# QTableModel does not seem to show on a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my code for my `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QSqlDatabase connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    connection.setHostName("localhost");
    connection.setDatabaseName("dbname");
    connection.setUserName("username");
    connection.setPassword("Temp");



    QTableView *view = new QTableView(this);

    view->setMinimumSize(200, 200);

    QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(this, connection);
    model->setTable("users");
    qDebug()  << model->columnCount() << model->rowCount();
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model->select();
    model->removeColumn(0); // don't show the ID



    view->setModel(model);

    view->show();

    this->setWindowTitle("Showing Things");
}
```

My `main.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I **know** my database contains data, I am basically following the example from the Detailed Explanation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqltablemodel.html).

This is what I get when I compile and run:

[image: nada]

When I expect something like this:

[image: what I want]

and I **do not** get it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've not used QMainWindow in a while, but could it be as simple as (in your MainWindow constructor) saying this->setCentralWidget(view), instead of, or maybe in addition to, view->Show()?

Comment: @kenrogers I have tried that to no avail... :-( -- I just get the same results.

Comment: You're certain that after doing model->select(), there's really data in the model? I notice that you're not checking the return value from select(). And there's no call to connection.open().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code you posted, you didn't open the database connection.

`QSqlTableModel` doesn't open it for you.

Comment: Why thank you very much sir! That saved a lot of heartache... I must have deleted that line by accident at one point and I did not see it....